# Children must, should, have to or ought to go to school?

Tags: usage

Took a test at WWW.SPEAK-UP.COM.UA. One of the questions was:

CHILDREN ..... GO TO SCHOOL.

- must
- should
- have to - CORRECT
- ought to

What's the difference? Can other variants be considered grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I wonder what the directions said. If this is a question about grammar, it's a terrible question.

Comment: The directions said: "Check your knowledge, enroll for a course!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all gramattically correct, but all have different meanings, so it depends what you mean to convey:

"**Must**" and "**have to**" imply that it is *compulsory* for children to attend school.

"**Should**" and "**ought to**" imply more a personal preference that you believe they should.

One reason why "*have to*" may have been selected as correct over the similar "*must*" could be because it sounds less dogmatic. Actually, it isn't strictly correct that *all* children *must* attend school because it ignores any starting age. In my country children aged 2 do not attend school, although they *will have to* when they reach aged 4.

Comment: But gramatically they are correct, aren't they?

Comment: @Zak Yes they are, added that point to the start of my answer as well as some further suggestion as to why one was "correct".